# can I declare a static array with constexpr function

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

```
// since we can dedfine a static array like this
int a[5] = {0};
// decltype(a[5]) is `int [5]`

// Then how about this way?
constexpr int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int a, b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
int arr[sum(a, b)] = {0};
```

---

it can be compiled successfully, but is `arr` a static array?
when I tried to print `arr` type with `typeid().name()` or `boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr`, I got below error:

```
error: cannot create type information for type 'int [(<anonymous> + 1)]' because it involves types of variable size
 std::cout << typeid(decltype(arr)).name() << std::endl;
```

Comment: It is not a static array unless you mark it as such.

Comment: a and b should be const also.

Comment: Declaring an array with size produced by `sum` invocation requires it to be invoked at *compile time*, for  function `sum` to be evaluated to compile time both arguments are required to be known at *compile time*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the value of `a` and `b` are not known at compile time the result of `sum` is not a constexpr.

The code compiles presumably because you are using GCC which has an extension which allows declaring arrays on the stack with variable size, standard c++ doesn't allow this.

Comment: Just a note that these are called _variable length arrays_ (VLA): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html. You can disable them with GCC by using `-Werror=vla`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/iJtZ5nmyDTaxFW2E.